# bootstrap tooltip trigering on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I want to show a message using bootstraps tooltip when the user enters more than 50 000 in an input.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {           

            $(this).tooltip("hide");

            $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
                console.log(this.value);
                if (this.value > 5000) {
                    $(this).tooltip("show");
                    $(this).val(50000);
                } else {
                    $(this).tooltip("hide");
                }
            }).tooltip({
                placement: "right",
                trigger: "focus"
            });

          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="myInput" title="You cannot enter more than 50 000" /> 
    </body>
</html>
```

or see http://jsfiddle.net/Ljxz2/

The problem is that tooltip is triggering the message on focus (I think), so the message is shown when the user clicks (or focuses) the input. How do I turn that off?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the value of "trigger" in the options sent in the tooltip function call to "manual".

```
tooltip({
    placement: "right",
    trigger: "manual"
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YcQat/

Comment: ahhh, just that easy. Thanks alot!